# How to reload a view-controller after data has been fetched from a network request?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem and can't seem to fix it after looking at tutorials online and other SO questions with a similar problem, which leaves me to think I've done something wrong/bad practice related in my code.

I have 2 table view controllers.

The first TableViewController is populated from a database, all this works fine.  When I click one of the cells it segues to a second TableViewController which also should be populated from a database (depending on what you select in the first VC).

Currently if I click a cell in TVC1 it goes to TVC2 and it's empty, then it I click back within my navigation controller and select something else, it goes back to TVC2 and shows me my first selection.  This indicates that TVC2 is being loaded before the network has returned its data from the database.... so, I tried using tableView.reloadData() in various places like viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, but i just can't seem to get it to work.

Below is both TVC's.  I've stuck with MVC design pattern and haven't included the model and severConnection code for each TVC because I don't want to over complicate the post, however if you'd like to see either I will update.

Thanks in advance for any help.

TableViewController1

```
class MenuTypeTableViewController: UITableViewController, MenuTypeServerProtocol {

//Properties
var cellItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectedItem = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let menuTypeServer = MenuTypeServer()
    menuTypeServer.delegate = self
    menuTypeServer.downloadItems()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "cellType"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    let item: MenuTypeModel = cellItems[indexPath.row] as! MenuTypeModel
    myCell.textLabel?.text = item.type
    return myCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    selectedItem = (selectedCell?.textLabel?.text)!
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "typeItems" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TypeItemsTableViewController
        destinationVC?.selectedItem = self.selectedItem
    }
}
}
```

TableViewController2:

```
class TypeItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController, TypeItemsServerProtocol {

//Properties
var cellItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectedItem: String = String()
let typeItemsServer = TypeItemsServer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    typeItemsServer.delegate = self
    self.typeItemsServer.foodType = self.selectedItem
    self.typeItemsServer.downloadItems()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "cellTypeItem"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    let item: TypeItemsModel = cellItems[indexPath.row] as! TypeItemsModel
    myCell.textLabel?.text = item.name!
    return myCell
}

}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the essential parts. Stuff like `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` is no help but clutter to the question.

Comment: I apologise, let me update

Comment: You could add a callback to your download items so when it's finished you refresh your data. Another possibility is that your create an delegate, you subscribe to that delegate and when your items is downloaded you call the delegate and in your tableviewcontroller you implement what should be done when that delegate is called, in your case reload the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark.  I've tried what you said and  Still same result :/ Any more ideas ?

I did the following in my server class
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: types)
        }
and implemented itemsDownloaded in my TVC and called tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Did you debug and make sure the delegate is called in the TVC? Problem I sometimes had is that I forget to add ServerClass.delegate = self. If you did that, you could also try the callback option I mentioned. If you need an example I could provide that @JamesJust-Gaming

Comment: Hi MarkI managed to fix the problem, I'll copy and paste my response below:
I found the problem, I feel a bit silly now, but I shall put it down to the excuse of "This is my first application..." ;) Basically, in my first table view controller I was overriding didSelectRowAt, and I was passing the title of the selected row to the second VC by updating a global var in the first vc then passing it within the segue. It was the segue that was performing before it had this variable, so now I removed the segue all together and I've pushed to the second VC programmatically and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance :)

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your problem @JamesJust-Gaming. Never feel excused to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to `TypeItemsTableViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cellItems = NSArray()//make sure you have the empty array at the start
    typeItemsServer.delegate = self
    self.typeItemsServer.foodType = self.selectedItem
    self.typeItemsServer.downloadItems()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    typeItemsServer.delegate = nil
}
```

Add this at the top

```
var cellItems: NSArray = NSArray() {
    didSet {
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now you can remove other `tableview.reloadData()` calls since it will automatically be called once `cellItems` are set...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added both of these and unfortunately I get the same outcome. :(

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I'm going to now assume I have a problem elsewhere, maybe inside my TypeItemsServer class.  I will investigate there now I've made these changes.  Thanks for your time and effort.  I will make this as the correct answer.

Comment: sure, if you have any other questions let me know

Comment: I found the problem, I feel a bit silly now, but I shall put it down to the excuse of "This is my first application..." ;)  Basically, in my first table view controller I was overriding didSelectRowAt, and I was passing the title of the selected row to the second VC by updating a global var in the first vc then passing it within the segue.  It was the segue that was performing before it had this variable, so now I removed the segue all together and I've pushed to the second VC programmatically and it works like a charm.

Comment: Great, `this is my first application` is a good excuse, just keep working on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a timing problem. You're reloading right after your async data call. You reload but your data isn't in place at that time. Try using functions with escaping or use "didSet" on your data like:

```
    var dataArray: [type] {
       didSet {
           tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }
```